pipenv takes 5x longer time now vs 1-2 months ago (bitbucket pipeline)
This applies in bitbucket pipelines.
For some reason, which is not clear to me, it takes 5x longer time to execute the command pipenv install today vs a couple of months ago.
We have also tested to rerun a pipeline that is approx 2 months old, and we have replicated the same behaviour. The original pipenv install command took approx 90 seconds, today it takes between 7-8 minutes.
One strange thing is that it seems like install process is executed several time. We get the message "Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (f1a8d8)..." 3-5 times everytime the pipenv install is executed.
pipenv install on my local environment (MacBook Pro M1, 32GB) takes approx 30 seconds.
The log from the pipeline at bitbucket looks like this:
pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project
Pipfile: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python3.12.7 to create virtualenv...
created virtual environment CPython3.12.7.final.0-64 in 302ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F, 
clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, via=copy, 
app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==24.3.1
  activators 
BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator
,PythonActivator
Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/build-3vGKWv3F
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (f1a8d8)...
All dependencies are now up-to-date!
Upgrading  in  dependencies.
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Success!
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Success!
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (f1a8d8)...
All dependencies are now up-to-date!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (f1a8d8)...


Are you using caches in the pipelines? Could you share the relevant fragments for your bitbucket-pipelines.yml? Can you re-try in your local environment after wiping any local cache?
